# How to get QC OTAClient dll version that registered using com4j

Tags: testng, hp-quality-center, com4j

I'm trying to update test results from TestNG and using com4j to connect from java. i was able to connect to QC but while accessing the test lab node i'm getting below error. While searching  through forums i found somewhere that it may be older version of OTAClient (ver 9). But i'm using version 11. how to get OTClient version using getTDVersion function? what values to provide for parameters of this function?

```
void getTDVersion(
    Holder<java.lang.String> pbsMajorVersion,
    Holder<java.lang.String> pbsBuildNum);
```

> Exception in thread "main" com4j.ComException: 800403ff (Unknown
> error) : Node not found. : .\invoke.cpp:517   at
> com4j.Wrapper.invoke(Wrapper.java:166)    at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.nodeByPath(Unknown Source)     at
> com.ca.qc.connection.getTestCases(connection.java:52)     at
> com.ca.qc.connection.main(connection.java:27) Caused by:
> com4j.ComException: 800403ff (Unknown error) : Node not found. :
> .\invoke.cpp:517  at com4j.Native.invoke(Native Method)   at
> com4j.StandardComMethod.invoke(StandardComMethod.java:35)     at
> com4j.Wrapper$InvocationThunk.call(Wrapper.java:340)  at
> com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)   at
> com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)  at
> com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)

Comment: The latest version of OTAClient.dll can be found in `C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Local\HP\ALM-Client\qualitycenter`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is availble at 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Mercury Interactive\Quality Center provided, you have accessed ALM client from your machine.